# Why saving a file to Android "External Storage" sometimes saves it to the "Internal Storage", sometimes to the "SD Card", and sometimes not at all?

Tags: android, android-external-storage, internal-storage

I am quite confused with the concept of External Storage. I have a following code underneath where I wanted to save my bitmap drawing into the Internal Storage.

```
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    File filePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File dir = new File(filePath.getAbsolutePath(), "/Test_Folder");
    
    if (dir == null || !dir.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e("File", "Directory not created");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Directory not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
    File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved to Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So in my Samsung Android, it saves into the "Internal Memory". For the Android Studio emulator, it saves into the "SD Card", and for some other devices, it would either Log or Toast "Directory not created".

I have read some very old posts about storage/emulated/0 is the chosen "default storage"? How do I target to a very specific storage type and why is it that sometimes other devices do not write?

**EDIT:**
Okay so I have now understood that as an Android User, the thing we perceive as "Internal Storage/Memory" is still technically "External Storage" (Thanks for making this clear! Do please correct me if I'm wrong)

So turns out this is our Android versions accordingly:

- Samsung : Android 13
- Emulator : Android 11
- 'Other Devices' : Android 9 and Android 10

It asked the `Will you allow this app to access files?` Prompt with `Allow` or `Deny` options for **Androids 11, 9, and 10.**

It can only save in **Androids 13 (No Prompt) , and 11 (With Prompt).**

Included this to check for versions:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + FolderName);
        Log.e("File", ">=R File:" + dir);
    }
    else
    {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + FolderName);
        Log.e("MountedMedia", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
        Log.e("File", "<R File:" + dir);
    }

    // Make sure the path directory exists.
    if (!dir.exists())
    {
        // Make it, if it doesn't exit
        boolean success = dir.mkdirs();
        if (!success)
        {
            dir = null;
            Log.e("File", "Directory not created");
        }
    }
```

But for the 'Other Devices', it would always Log `Directory not Created` even if I confirmed in the settings that Storage Permissions is allowed. Not sure if I miss something this time

Comment: Environment.getExternal.... is called external storage... not internal. But... it is in your device yes.

Comment: Only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist yet. And if you call mkdirs() then stop if it returns false. You now blindly continue.

Comment: "So in my Samsung Android, it saves into the "Internal Memory". For the Android Studio emulator, it saves into the "SD Card"" -- that sounds right. "External storage" [is an Android SDK term](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not an end-user term. "and for some other devices, it would either Log or Toast "Directory not created"" -- you do not have write access to arbitrary locations on external storage on Android 11+.

Comment: `File dir = new File(filePath.getAbsolutePath(), "/Test_Folder");` Change to `File dir = new File(filePath,  "Test_Folder");`

Comment: which android version are you using?

Comment: @Lino I edited my question to include the Android versions and what happened (I apologize, idk why everytime I try to tag, it just would not tag)

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for the explanation. So does this mean that either "Internal Phone Storage" or "SD Card" wouldn't really matter and would just depend on what the user uses as default storage? As the developer, do you have power to choose which one to write files into?

Comment: @blackapps Interesting. Okay I will attempt that

Comment: `wouldn't really matter and would just depend on what the user uses as default storage?` No. It just depends on which file manager or file explorer the user uses that comes up with such descriptions.

Comment: "So does this mean that either "Internal Phone Storage" or "SD Card" wouldn't really matter and would just depend on what the user uses as default storage?" -- "SD Card" as where primary external storage goes is an emulator thing. Take the emulator seriously, but not literally. Beyond that, though, the naming is largely up to the device manufacturer.

Comment: "As the developer, do you have power to choose which one to write files into?" -- if you mean you want to support [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), you have limited rights there through standard filesystem APIs. Please consider using the Storage Access Framework and allowing the *user* to choose where you should store the *user's* data on the *user's* phone (or the *user's* chosen cloud storage provider).